# Website crawling based on keyword in Excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I would like to crawl the website price based on the search keyword on my keyword.xlsx file , the first input should be dyson, second is lego, third input should be sony, but my result in the attached image only has dyson, do you know why?

[image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sL7lw.jpg)

```
import time
from random import randint
import ast
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #A python library to help you to exract HTML information
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}


import xlrd
import pandas as pd
df_keywords = pd.read_excel('keyword.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', usecols="A")
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('keyword.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
index=df_keywords.index
number_of_row=len(index)
print(number_of_row)

#worksheet.cell(2,0).value

for i in range (1,number_of_row+1):

    keyword_input=worksheet.cell(i,0).value
    print (keyword_input)
    
    
    

   

    
    prefix="https://tw.buy.yahoo.com/search/product?disp=list&p="
    sortbyprice="&sort=price"
    url=prefix+keyword_input+sortbyprice

    r=requests.get(url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text)


    for i in soup.findAll("div", {"class":"ListItem_price_2CMKZ"}): 
        lowest=i.find("span",{"class":"ListItem_priceContent_5WbI9"}).text.strip()
        print(lowest)
        lowest_first=lowest.split("",1)[0]
        print(lowest_first)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues here. First, I'm not sure what `lowest_first=lowest.split("",1)[0]` is supposed to be doing in your code. It is throwing an error in your code preventing it from hitting the next iteration of your for loop. You can't split a string on nothing (""). If you are trying to get rid of the '$', you can just do `lowest[1:]`.

Second, you can accomplish your task directly from `pandas` without having to call `xlrd` (which is often used as the backend engine for reading excel files (along with `openpyxl`).

```py
import pandas as pd
df_keywords = pd.read_excel('keyword.xlsx')
for keyword in df_keywords['keyword'].to_list():
    prefix="https://tw.buy.yahoo.com/search/product?disp=list&p="
    print(prefix + keyword)
```

Output

```
https://tw.buy.yahoo.com/search/product?disp=list&p=dyson
https://tw.buy.yahoo.com/search/product?disp=list&p=lego
https://tw.buy.yahoo.com/search/product?disp=list&p=sony
```